# Incrementally find number of disjoint sets in reduced graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, disjoint-sets, union-find

I find the number of disjoint sets in a graph `G` and then I delete some vertices of graph `G` and make graph `G'`, and I want to find the number of disjoint sets in `G'`, is there any good algorithm for that without doing the same thing to `G'` as we did to `G`?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing this in reverse order.

By this I mean:

1. Start with the smallest graph G' and use the union find algorithm to find the disjoint sets.
2. Then add the new elements in G and join some additional sets together by continuing to use the union find algorithm starting from the output from step 1.
3. Repeat adding new vertices and finding disjoint sets as many times as necessary

The reason the reverse order is better is because you only need to visit the new vertices in step 2 so you don't end up repeating lots of work for each new graph.